# Why can't I duplicate faces in place?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to duplicate a loop of faces on a bottle shape to create a label.
I can do it successfully if I drag the duplicate faces away from the original bottle and then separate the vertices by selection.
Problem is, when I leave the duplicate vertices in place and the try to separate them by selection, Blender then deletes the original faces underneath the new faces, leaving me with a hole in my bottle.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you might have *Auto merge* enabled in *3D view > Header*.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look and see if it is.

Comment: Where do I find "Auto Merge"? I looked and am not finding that option.

Comment: Ok, I found Auto Merge. Its not selected. Thats not the problem. What else can I try?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. You have to hit return/enter right after you hit Duplicate. This locks in the duplication. If you don't do that, Blender deletes the underlying verts once you do the separation step. Voila.

Comment: @ThomasBricker Please add that as an answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> right after you hit Duplicate with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This locks in the duplication. If you don't do that, Blender deletes the underlying verts once you do the separation step.